# Vim CSS styles syntax highlight in .html or .vue files not working

Tags: html, css, vim, syntax-highlighting, nuxt.js

I'm trying to highlight CSS syntax in .html and .vue files but it does not work as the screenshot shows : https://i.ibb.co/XDFKwTx/Screenshot-from-2019-04-22-18-13-46.png

I've tried to use the plugin https://github.com/posva/vim-vue but the result is the same than the native HTML plugin.

My ~/.vimrc :

```c
syntax on
set number
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
set autoread
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=utf-8
set fileformat=unix
set fileformats=unix,dos

autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.vue,*.ts: set filetype=html

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'sgur/vim-editorconfig'
call plug#end()
```

Answer (score 0):

It was actually linked to the Nuxt.js code generator in `<template></template>` tag.

Before :

```
<template>
  ...
  <a 
    href="https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js"
    target="_blank"
    class="button--grey"
    >GitHub<
  /a>

</template>
```

After:

```
<template>
  ...
  <a 
    href="https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js"
    target="_blank"
    class="button--grey"
   >
    GitHub
   </a>

</template>
```